# How to fix Ethernet interface name?

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet, interface

On my TX2 device I have two interfaces `eth0` and an additional `enp1s0`.

The problem is that sometimes the first interface is `eth0` and sometimes `eth1` after boot. `enp1s0` is always `enp1s0`.

How can I make sure that I always get `eth0` as the first interface and not `eth1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign static names to devices using udev and the mac addresses of the ports.

Create

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/99-persistent-net.rules
```

And add:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:25:69:62:r3:c1", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="eth1"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:25:69:62:r3:c2", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="eth0"
```

Making sure to change the mac address to that of your adapters. They can be found with the `ifconfig` command. Reboot your PC once all that is done.

See for more info:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html

Comment: What if I have, let's say, tens of devices? One cannot manually configure each one of them.

Comment: While there may be a way to do this with udev, I dont have the knowledge to accomplish it. I personally would look at writing a bash script to iterate over your devices and create rules to use.